# I need to know how to output an excel file from a servlet

Tags: java, excel, servlets, web

So, I am writing a java servlet. The user goes to the servlet and they automatically are  prompted to download or open the excel file. How do I do this? I have the excel file in my webcontent folder. I know it's pretty elementary, but I've always been bad at the file and outputstream and inputstream stuff.

Comment: Depending on your server setup, you may just be able to link to the file and the web browser will, knowing not to attempt to display it, offer it for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have the excel file in my webcontent folder*

Just link to it directly. The servletcontainer's builtin default servlet will then worry about the streaming and setting the proper headers.

```html
<a href="filename.xls">Download filename.xls</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sampleName.xls");
```

and then pipe the file contents to the response.getOutputStream